# Selecting data from a table on button click

Tags: c#, sql, datagridview

I am trying to fetch a table into a `DataGridView`, but it shows an empty table.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var dt = new DataTable();

    var SDA = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * from "+txt_Search.Text+" ", conn);

    SDA.Fill(dt);
    dgv.DataSource = dt;
    txt_Search.Text = "";
}
```

Comment: The first thing to do is put a breakpoint in your code and check if dt has any data in it at the point you are assigning it as a DataSource.

Comment: @ChrisBerger -- No the first think to do is run for cover because the sql injection attacks are going to be catastrophic.

Comment: It is hard to tell whats wrong here. First, make sure that you arent ignoring `A first chance of XXXXException...`. And test each step: is `conn` opened successfully? is the table name a reserved keywords?(may want to quote that with [] or \`\`) does the table contains data? ...etc

Comment: @Hogan - Well, you do have a point.  I was assuming that the only person who will ever type into txt_Search is the programmer, because it just looks like someone trying to learn how to code.  But it IS important to point out that you should never include user-provided text in a query string.  Normally you would use parameterized queries, but of course you cannot do that with the table name.  If the OP actually wants to do that, they will want to verify that it's a valid table name.  (And probably just shouldn't do this.)

Comment: Once that is solved, you need to think about [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). Since malicious user may attempt to search something like `random_table; drop table important_table".

Comment: If this a web solution, you should add `dgv.DataBind` to bind the data to the grid

Comment: connection is successful , table_name is also not a reserved keyword.

Comment: its winform app.

Answer (score 0):

The code snippet you've provided doesn't give much context.Try using the below snippet I've provided. Maybe you see something you've missed. Hope this helps.

```
const string connectionString = "";
SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString)

public DataTable ExecuteCommandToDataTable(string commandText, CommandType 
commandType, int timeout, params SqlParameter[] parameters)
{
    if (this.connection == null)
        throw new NullReferenceException("The connection was not initialized.");

    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(commandText, 
    this.connection.SqlConnection);            
    command.CommandType = commandType;
    command.CommandTimeout = timeout;

    for (int i = 0; parameters != null && i < parameters.Length; i++)
        command.Parameters.Add(parameters[i]);


    this.connection.Open();

    DataTable tbl = new DataTable();
    using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCommand))
    {
        adapter.Fill(tbl);
    }

    this.connection.Close();

    return tbl;
}
```